# Directing to a webpage after comparing a input variable in perl webpage

Tags: forms, perl, cgi, html

So what I'm trying to do here is to build a couple for webpages. So there is main page(say m1). so m1 has just a input field and a submit button.
So what I want to do is get the variable (a string) from the input field in main page and then compare it with a set of strings and then redirect to the corresponding webpage. 
For example, if I enter "blue" in input field, it should take the value, compare it with set of values and redirect to corresponding webpage(maybe a page with blue background)

Here is the code I'm trying with, which I got after a long search.

```
 use CGI qw/:standard :html3/;

 # this defines the contents of the fill out forms
 # on each page.
 @PAGES = ('Main','Blue','Red','Yellow','Green');
 %FIELDS = ('Main' => ['Name'],
            );
 # accumulate the field names into %ALL_FIELDS;
 foreach (values %FIELDS) {
 grep($ALL_FIELDS{$_}++,@$_);
 } 


 # figure out what page we're on and where we're heading.
 $current_page = calculate_page(param('page'),param('go'));
 $page_name = $PAGES[$current_page];

 print_header();
 print_form($current_page)         if $FIELDS{$page_name};
 print_review($current_page)       if $page_name eq 'Review';
 print_confirmation($current_page) if $page_name eq 'Confirmation';
 print end_html;

 # CALCULATE THE CURRENT PAGE
 sub calculate_page {
 my ($prev,$dir) = @_;
 return 0 if $prev eq '';   # start with first page
 return $prev + 1 if $dir eq 'Submit Application';
 return $prev + 1 if $dir eq 'Next Page';
 return $prev - 1 if $dir eq 'Previous Page';
 }

 # PRINT HTTP AND HTML HEADERS
 sub print_header {
 print header,
 start_html("Your Friendly Family Loan Center"),
 h1("Your Friendly Family Loan Center"),
 h2($page_name);
 }

 # PRINT ONE OF THE QUESTIONNAIRE PAGES
 sub print_form {
 my $current_page = shift;
 print "Please enter the name",
    start_form,
    hr;
 draw_form(@{$FIELDS{$page_name}});
 print hr;
 print submit(-name=>'go',-value=>'Previous Page') 
    if $current_page > 0;
 print submit(-name=>'go',-value=>'Submit'), 
    hidden(-name=>'page',-value=>$current_page,-override=>1),
    end_form;
 }
```

My Question is how do I access the variable that is Submitted in first page and how to compare with the set of variables ? when I say set of variables it means a array which has values  red blue green yellow

Comment: Where did you get this code, or what resources did you use? This stuff is at least over 10 years old. Probably 15.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the redirect header

[CGI.pm: Generating a Redirection Header](https://metacpan.org/module/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.63/lib/CGI.pm#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER)

To elaborate, once you've computed the next URL, you add a redirect header to tell the browser to go there. There are two ways. The first way is to call redirect($new_url). The second is to call header('Location', $new_url).

I've found that sometimes, the redirect() method doesn't work for me, and I have to resort to the header() method.  But that may have been my old, old version of CGI.pm.

The other thing to remember, is that neither of those methods end your request processing. They simply add a header to the response's header list.  It's up to you to exit correctly from your script.

Comment: How did you come up with that from the question? Did I completely misunderstand the OP?

Comment: @simbabque, Here's how: "For example, if I enter "blue" in input field, it should take the value, compare it with set of values and redirect to corresponding webpage(maybe a page with blue background)"

Comment: It happens. No blood, no foul.

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your question:

You can create an object from your CGI module like this:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
```

Put that at the top. The object has a couple of methods. One of them is `$cgi->param()`. You can use it to get your form's values. So if you have a field called `action`, you could look at it like this:

```
my $action = $cgi->param('action');
```

In your case, you have a field called `Name` that you want to compare to an array.

```
my @colors = qw( red blue green yellow );
for (my $i=0; $ <= $#colors; $i++) {
  if ( $colors[$i] eq $cgi->param('Name') ) {
    print "<p>You have entered $colors[$i]. ";
    print "It was the $i. element in the array!</p>";
  }
}
```

We making an iteration variable `$i` that is counted from 0 to the number of elements in `@colors`. We are then comparing each of these elements to the form variable.

You can find more information on how this works [in the manual for CGI](https://metacpan.org/module/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.63/lib/CGI.pm#FETCHING-THE-VALUE-OR-VALUES-OF-A-SINGLE-NAMED-PARAMETER) on CPAN.

---

I'll not go into the details of how not very modern Perl your code is. If you want to improve, get a modern Perl book that was written after 2010. But please start with using [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial where I can learn perl for creating webpages ? from simple to complex step by step ? i searched a lot and had no luck.thanks

Comment: @mac Take a look at http://perl-tutorial.org/. There are lots of good tutorials linked there. Make sure to read ones that have `use strict` and `use warnings`, and that do not refert to Perl as `PERL` as those are very old and will likely not help you.